# AndroidTest org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class

Tags: android, kotlin, koin, uitest

I am trying to mock viewmodel in mu android test but i am getting this error

> org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for
> class:'com.example.berlinclockdemo.ui.MainActivityViewModel'. Check
> your definitions!

How can I solve this error? or is there any alternate way of doing this. All I want
to do is manipulate viewmodel live data so that I can check my UI for my desired data
EX: `Recyclerview` data needs to show what my expected data is.

Below is my code
My ViewModel
`MainActivityViewModel`:

```
  class MainActivityViewModel(private val berlinClock: BerlinClock) : ViewModel() {

  var berlinClockTime = MutableLiveData<BerlinClockData>()
  val berlinClockValue: LiveData<BerlinClockData> = berlinClockTime

  fun updateBerlinClock(time: String) {
     berlinClockTime.postValue(berlinClock.getBerlinClock(time))
  }
}
```

My Test Activity
MainAvtivityTest:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class MainActivityKakaoTest : KoinTest {
@Rule
@JvmField
val rule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

private val mockedBerlinClock: BerlinClock = mockk()

private val appModule = module {
    single { mockedBerlinClock }
}
private val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel {
        MainActivityViewModel
        (get())
    }
}

private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by inject()

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)

    val expectedBerlinTime =
        (getBerlinClockData(arrayOf("RRRR RRRR", "YYROOOOOOOO YYOO", "O")))

    loadKoinModules(
        listOf(
            appModule, viewModelModule
        )
    )

    every {
        mockedBerlinClock.getBerlinClock(
            SimpleDateFormat(
                MainActivity.TIME_FORMAT,
                Locale.getDefault()
            ).format(Date())
        )
    } returns expectedBerlinTime

    viewModel.updateBerlinClock(
        SimpleDateFormat(MainActivity.TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()).format(
            Date()
        )
    )
    assertThat(expectedBerlinTime).isEqualTo(viewModel.berlinClockValue.value)
}
   }


  TestApplication:
       
  class TestApp : Application() {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoin {
        androidLogger(Level.NONE)
        androidContext(this@TestApp)
        modules(emptyList())
    }
   }
  }

 TestRunner:
       class TestAppJUnitRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
     override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: 
  Context?): Application {
    return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp::class.java.name, context)
 }
  }
```